# Can't get all friends via "Graph API"

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are developing one APP to sync Facebook friends to phone contact, and we try to gain contacts via "Graph API" according the API Reference:

Friends: https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=...

But we failed to get all friends of my Facebook account. It is always that some friend not in the returning JSON data.

In one of my test account, there are 19 friends, but always lose 1 specify friends, no matter how many times I try.

I use other account, there are 136 friends, but lose 10 friends.

The "Graph API" is only open part data to developer or the facebook can't return the correct result?

Are there anyone else meet this problem?  Or there is anything more to look out on how to gain the friend?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Like it was explained here before – if a user disables all apps on the platform, your app will not be able to “see” him **at all.** And that includes friend lists – if a friend of yours disabled platform apps altogether, then you will **not** get them returned via the `/me/friends` connection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I want to know, this info is comes from 
experience or some documents? How can I get more info about it?

Comment: How to disable all apps on platform? I try to remove all items in "App Settings", but the friend still able be "see" to others!!!! Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, sir. You're right. I try to turn off Platform apps via "Privacy Settings > Ads, Apps and Websites > turn off Platform apps", the user is not able be "see". But why the user still can be "see" in "Facebook APP"?

Answer (score 0):

use [Hackbook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/hackbook/) for this.  it have graph_or_fql both way to get friends

Comment: SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me(). both methods will lose some friends.

Comment: dear friend ..

it works perfect..

you need to check total number of deactivate facebook id of friends and count them and subtraction of your total number of friends..

and do't see total number of friends just count your self in facebook..

Comment: Dear Amit, thanks for your rely, but how to judge if the Facebook id is a deactivate one? thanks.

Comment: your friend profile pic have not Photo and you can't see him.

Comment: The deactivated account can not be accessed by anyone, even the owner of the account.

So there is no use to get the details or listing of these kind of accounts displayed in the app.

Answer (score 0):

use offset and limit

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token= &offset= &limit
```